# My jQuery $.post function returning a value but can't compare it

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure why the if/else statement, when comparing response to success, isn't coming up true. The first alert, alerts "success" but then when I try to compare it...it isn't finding it to be true. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
    $("#suggestion_button_box").click(function(){     
    var suggestion = $("#suggest_input_id").serialize();

    if(suggestion != "") {
        $.post('suggest_tag.php',suggestion, function(response) {

            alert(response);    

            if(response == "success") {
                alert('yes');       
            }else {
                alert('no');
            }

    });

    }
});
```

PHP part

```
echo "success";
```

Comment: `alert`, `document.write` is bad way to debug your scripts. Use some tools like firebug and `console.log(variable)` instead for debugging, as `alert(array('foo'));` will show you same thing as `alert('foo');` In this example `response` might be: array, object, string. You don't know.

Comment: What content type is coming back? jQuery might be interpreting this as a different type of content than just a string.

Comment: I `echo "success";` in a php file.

Comment: please post a sample of your PHP as part of your question - it would help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

As I had mentioned above - jQuery may be interpreting the result string as something other than just plain text.  By default, [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) attempts to intelligently guess the type of data being returned. The API offers 4 parameter options, try setting the fourth parameter (dataType) to 'text' and see if it starts behaving.

**EDIT**

I noticed your comment above and this changes things, so 'data' is now potentially an XML/HTML element.

You'll have to see if the returned object is an XML element if so, you can do a DOM traversal and possibly retrieve by doing $(response).text().

**EDIT 2**
Are you getting back a response <code>"success"</code> or were you attempting to indicate that it was <?php echo "success";?>?

Comment: when my first `alert(response);` is executed...I am alerted "success" but after that I am alerted "no".

Comment: are the quotes included in the alert? (just clarifying here)

Comment: Again - please post a sample of your PHP code - that will greatly clear up the client & server side interactions.

Answer (score 0):

From my expiriance, there is probably some white character in one of your PHP scripts ( i.e. before

If this doesn't solve your problem, you can always use JS trim() function like this:

```
if(response.trim() == "success") {
```

Or even jQuery.trim() which is more crossbrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#suggestion_button_box").click(function(){
    var suggestion = $("#suggest_input_id").val();
    if(suggestion != "")
    {
        $.post('suggest_tag.php', { suggestion : suggestion },
        function(response) {
            alert(response);    
            if(response == "success") {
                alert('yes');       
            }else {
                alert('no');
            }
        });
    }
});
```